# how to implement golang ssh gateway

Tags: go, ssh, gateway

I want to implement a ssh golang gateway with golang custom hooks on authorisation and requests. Schematically it looks like this (`ssh-gateway` is a server that I want to implement):

```
client <--> ssh-gateway <--> ssh-server
               ↓
            auth handler
            + request handler
```

I found a golang package for that - [`sshr`](https://github.com/tsurubee/sshr), but it uses quite old fork of `golang.org/x/crypto` that has `proxy.go` implementation. And this `proxy.go` unfortunately doesn't exist in the head version (or I didn't find it).

My best guess was something like [here](https://sosedoff.com/2015/05/25/ssh-port-forwarding-with-go.html) where the author creates `net.Conn` connections with `ssh.Dial` and copies (`io.Copy(client, remote)`) from one to another and vice versa. But this doesn't work for me as well because

```
listener, _ := net.Listen("tcp", "0.0.0.0:2222")
conn, _ := listener.Accept()
```

returns `ssh.ServerConn` that can't be copied.

Any ideas how I can implement it or how to copy `ssh.ServerConn` to `net.Conn` and and vice versa?